# Projetos não aparecem no Package Explorer do Eclipse

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Meus projetos Android não aparecem no Package Explorer do Eclipse.

O que devo fazer para que eles apareçam?

Answer (score 1):

1) Clique em File/Import
2) Procure e abra a pasta General
3) Escolha a opção Existing Projects in Workspace e clique no botão Next
4) Na opção Select root directory, clique no botão browse  e escolha o seu diretorio de workspace
5) Selecione os projetos desejados e clique em Finish
6) Bom Trabalho ;)

Answer (score -1):

Na opção Select root directory, clique no botão browse e escolha o seu diretorio de workspace (Meu Projeto Aparece mas não consigo selecionar)